# automate version number via make file

Tags: makefile, version-control, automation, versioning

I am currently using a binary from a 3rd party source and make changes to its configs in order to integrate it with our master branch. Every time I do it we increase the version number of our build. As of now, it's done manually in the C file that comes with the binary. I am planning to automate it in a way such that every time I merge binary with master the build number increments. Also, we use a makefile to build the master. Is there a way I could do that via makefile or in the C file itself. Is this possible? are there any posts or links someone can refer me to?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about how you plan `make` to automate which step? Increasing a number which resides solo in a text file can be done easily in a number of ways but maybe your versioning requires more detail?

Comment: I have a C file that comes with the binary. The versioning is implemented in such a way that when we merge the binary with our source code we manually update the build number in the that C file. It's kind of a hack:
 unsigned int VERSION = (x << 24) + (y << 16) + (z << 8) + 0;
where x, y, z are ints , we change these in order to increment the build numbers.
The **make** is used to build the project and create a directory with the same version number that we updated manually. I am looking for a way to auto increment the version or may be use a text (like you suggested) in order to do that.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) for a library which helps you to count an manipulate strings.